# Simulate React events in minified code in iframe

Tags: reactjs, testing

I have files `main.js` and `test.js`, containing compiled clojurescript code.

When I open `my-site.com/test`, it loads `test.js`, which adds an iframe to the page that loads `my-site.com/main`, which in turn loads `main.js`.  `test.js` then tests various user interactions with `my-site.com/main` inside the iframe.

The problem is that I'm using `React`, so I need to simulate `React` events.  Part of the reason I'm using this iframe structure is because I learned that `React.addons.TestUtils` is not loaded in minified code.  I thought that, by leaving `test.js` un-minified, I woud be able to use its version of `React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate` to simulate `React` events in `main.js`, even if the latter is minified.  I thought this would enable me to test production code.

What I found through much trial and error was that, when `main.js` is not minified, I can use its version of `Simulate` just fine, but when it is minified, I can't use `Simulate` from `test.js` on elements in `main`.

Am I right?  Is it possible to use `React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate` if the library wasn't loaded in the relevant window?  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

After hours' more trial and error, I finally discovered that I don't need to use `ReactTestUtils.Simulate` at all.  I had never been able to trigger events in my `React` DOM before, but it turns out that all I needed to do was set `bubbles: true` on a regular `Event` for it to trigger the appropriate `React` event.

Moreover, since the event I was trying to simulate was a "keyup", I also discovered that I can't set the `which` or `keyCode` property on a `KeyboardEvent`, at least in my browser (`which` and `keyCode` [are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)).  So I had to change my listener to look for `event.key` instead of `event.which`.  (I am still looking for `which` to accomodate older browsers, but I'm checking `key` first).

This works:

```js
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {key: "Enter", bubbles: true});
```

Hopefully this saves someone else some trouble!